# Gtx 780 upgrade seasonic g series 450rm

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

as of right now I have a seasonic 450rm power supply with 37 amps on the 12v rail. Its powering a mini itx motherboard with an i7 4770k on it and 16gb of 1.5v memory. The i7 is over clocked to 4.3ghz. Running a gtx 660 currently and the PSU has absolutely no problem powering it, about 240w at maximum load. If I were to upgrade to a gtx 780, not a crazy over clocked version, would my PSU still be ok? I'm thinking it'll be ok since if I add 150w its about 400w which is still below the rating, and I know seasonic PSUs are good for their full rating.

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you for your time!